# Group by with set of values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `product` table:

```
productid   product
1            A-110
2            B-110
3            C-400
4            D-401
```

And `orderditems` table:

```
orderitemid productid qty
1             1        10
2             2        10
3             3        10
4             3        10
5             4        10
```

I can group by based on product as:

```
select productid, sum(qty)
from ordereditems
group by productid
```

Which gives:

```
1    10
2    10
3    20
4    10
```

However for this query productid 1 & 2 , 3 & 4 are the same.
**Meaning that I want to see**:

```
1 + 2   20
3 + 4   30
```

Basically I want the query to understand that 1 & 2 are the same group and 3 & 4 are the same group.

How can i do that?

Edit:
Products 1 & 2 , 3 & 4 are not the same. However they are of the same family... What I want is to see how much we sell per family and not per product.
This is why the desired out put is:

```
1 + 2   20
3 + 4   30
```

Comment: Integer division by 2, somewhere.

Comment: why "productid 1 & 2 , 3 & 4 are the same"?..

Comment: @VaoTsun They are not, but for this query specifically they are the same. B-110 is of the same family of  A-110. I want to know how much we sell from the same families.

Comment: and how you specify the families?

Comment: @avi, If they are of same family, you must use another column to indicate the family tree and then use that column to `know how much we sell from the same families`

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I know that.. I'm asking if this is doable without chaining the table.. I need this only for one query.. Is it possible to determine the relationship requested within the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hacky version if you know that 1&2 are the same and 3&4 are the same, and those are the only things the same.

```
select 
  case 
    when productid in (1,2) then '1 + 2' 
    when productid in (3,4) then '3 + 4'
    else productid
  end as product_ids, sum(qty)
from ordereditems
group by 
  case 
    when productid in (1,2) then '1 + 2' 
    when productid in (3,4) then '3 + 4'
    else productid
  end
```

A better approach is to record in the database that two products are the same.  Either by linking the duplicated products (2,4) to the product they're the same as (1,3) or by creating a new table family etc.  and recording that products 1,2 are related to the same family.

family

```
familyid name
1         1+2
2         3+4
```

Extend product table

```
productid   product  familyid
1            A-110     1
2            B-110     1
3            C-400     2
4            D-401     2
```

then you can group on family

```
select f.name, sum(qty)
from ordereditems oi
inner join product p on oi.productid = p.productid
inner join family f on p.familyid = f.familyid
group by f.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls add a GroupID/Category field to your table.

```
productid   product    GroupID
1            A-110       A
2            B-110       A
3            C-400       B
4            D-401       B
```

Then use the query

```
select GroupID, sum(qty) as Sold
from ordereditems
group by GroupID
```

This will represent as group sale as if you have more than 10 products in a group your productid will make complicity to understand.

If it works for you pls mark as helpful.. :)

Comment: The user do not want to add another column. He only needs the sol with existing architecture.